# Powershell to add printers based on AD Site

Tags: powershell, printing

I am trying to map a default printer based on the location found in AD Sites and Services. I can grab the location of the computer using `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite]::GetComputerSite().Name`

Once I have grabbed the location, I would like it to map 2 printers based on the location. Each of our 10 sites has 2 default printers that I would like "Domain Users" to have. Then any security group related ones are mapped via another script I already have.

I already have a script in place using VB to do this - but as I am currently learning PS, I would like some pointers on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not create ten GPOs containing the 2 printers for each site, then link the GPOs to respective site?

Comment: But what if a user goes from one branch office to another, he/she will not get printers list updated and will use the printers in his/her native location.

Answer (score 1):

I love scripting, but this is probably one thing that you do not need to script. I think the most official and standard way to do this is by sharing the printers from a "print server," either one centralized one or a print server in each site. It is common practice to add this print server role onto another server that's already performing some other function, such as a file server. File and print services often go well together. Use the Print Management console to install, share, deploy and publish the printers. If you link a GPO to each site, and then deploy the printers using those site-linked GPOs, the users will get an updated list of printers as they move around between sites.

[image: Printers]

Comment: Can't upvote this enough; I love PowerShell, but this is a solved problem, and Ryan is demonstrating the correct way to address this. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

Setup All the printers for the users, and switch the deafult printer based on the site, for example:

```
$CurrentSite = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite]::GetComputerSite().Name

    Switch ($CurrentSite)
    {

    "SiteA" {
    $Printer = gwmi win32_printer -filter "Name='SiteA-PrinterName'"
    $Printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
    }

    "SiteB" {
    $Printer = gwmi win32_printer -filter "Name='SiteB-PrinterName'"
    $Printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
    }

    "SiteC" {
    $Printer = gwmi win32_printer -filter "Name='SiteC-PrinterName'"
    $Printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
    }

    "SiteD" {
    $Printer = gwmi win32_printer -filter "Name='SiteD-PrinterName'"
    $Printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi this is what i was looking for, but i want it to only map the printers for the site and not have all the printers installed - O/S is 8.1